# Liferay CSS URLs using http on secure pages

Tags: ssl, https, liferay, liferay-6

We're trying to upgrade an ancient Liferay instance to Liferay 6.2 on JBoss 6.4. We've got the front page loading over https but the CSS includes are all using http and therefore not loading properly. Is there a specific setting that controls this behavior? Should we be looking into the JBoss config or Liferay?

I can post more information but I'm honestly not sure where to start without posting everything we have.

Comment: As stackoverflow is focused on problems related to programming issues, and this is rather configuration/setup, you'd get better results on the Liferay forums. And yes, more information is needed. We can guide you through the necessary steps on the Liferay forums.

Comment: Have you yet tried to set web.server.protocol=https in your liferay portal properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try adding the property `web.server.protocol` to the file `portal-ext.properties` as Andre suggested.

Steps:

1. Stop the liferay server.
2. Edit or create the portal-ext.properties in the liferay home folder.
3. Add the property `web.server.protocol=https`
4. Start the liferay server